# Обработчик ошибок в MPI

Tags: c++, c, mpi

Я пытаюсь создать простой обработчик ошибок в `MPI`, выводящий что-то на экран, если процесс умирает во время работы.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void verbose_errhandler(MPI_Comm *pcomm, int* perr, ...) {
    MPI_Comm comm = *pcomm;
    int err = *perr;

    int i, rank, size, nf, len, eclass;
    char err_str[MPI_MAX_ERROR_STRING];
    MPI_Error_class(err, &eclass);
    MPI_Comm_size(comm, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &rank);
    MPI_Error_string(*perr, err_str, &len);
    printf("JFOJFSOJFDJFDOJFDOJFDDFOJ%d\n", rank);
}

int main(void) {
    MPI_Errhandler errh;
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_create_errhandler(verbose_errhandler, &errh);
    MPI_Comm_set_errhandler(MPI_COMM_WORLD, errh);
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank == 1) {
        raise(SIGKILL);
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Но когда я создаю и меняю `errhandler` при помощи команд `MPI_Comm_create_errhandler` и `MPI_Comm_set_errhandler`, при вызове `SIGKILL` на процессе `1` мой обработчик ошибок не вызывается. В чем тут может быть проблема? Буду благодарен.

Comment: The `SIGKILL` signal is used to cause immediate program termination. **It cannot be handled or ignored**, and **is therefore always fatal**. It is also not possible to block this signal.

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html

Comment: @EugeneX Could you please name signal, which will be handled with MPI errhandler? I tried simple in-code zero division,  SIGINT, SIGKILL, SIGSEGV, but none of these called `verbose_errhandler`

Comment: Also SIGTERM does not work

Comment: Если процесс умирает во время работы, то надо генерировать coredump, а не пилить какие-то обработчики. Обработчика по-умолчанию `MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL` должно быть достаточно.

Comment: Когда программа мультипроцессорная и только один из процессов полетел, можно не убивать всю программу, а

1) перераспределить его кусок работы на остальные процессы 
2) создать новый процесс, который довыполнит его работу 
3) использовать резервный процесс по логике п.2, который был создан заранее в самом начале программы.

Для этого нужно обработать процесс перед его смертью, чтобы понять, кого именно мы заменяем

Comment: @WrongWizzli Просто выписал часть мануала. Я уже точно не помню, лет 20 назад проходили сигналы. Так вот, SIGKILL это всё - полный 3.14ц процессу, скорое аварийное завершение, остановка и выгрузка всех потоков, была программа и всё, не осталось от неё и следа. SIGTERM - тоже является аварийным терминатором процесса, но процессу разрешено закончить активные процессы, при этом он не может создавать процессы, потоки и открывать handles ему сообщается о том что он сейчас сдохнет, и он может отменить этот сигнал. SIGQUIT - стандартное завершение процесса, просто говорим ну всё ты должен закрыться.